# EclipseLink Configuration in Wildfly-10.1.0.Final not reflecting the PersistenceProvider

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, wildfly-10

I am using EclipseLink as a JPA Implementation. While deploying in Wildfly-10.1.0.Final, I always get the error `No Persistence provider for EntityManager named <the persistence unit name>`. I have followed the step in the links:

1. https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-UsingEclipseLink
2. https://developer.jboss.org/thread/273134

The steps and the module.xml exactly matches mine.In standalone.xml I have enabled the system property as stated in the first link mentioned above

I enabled the trace logging and found that the below :
[org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] (default task-4) Excluding from consideration due to name mis-match

Persistence Provider :org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
JDK Version :1.8

Request if someone can shed some light where I am going wrong.

Added the trace as

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named AAAAA_BBBB
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
```

Other trace of Mismatch

```
2017-02-23 17:47:09,276 DEBUG [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] (default task-55) Checking persistence-unit [name=AAAAA_BBBB, explicit-provider=org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider] against incoming persistence unit name [AAAAA_BBBB]
2017-02-23 17:47:09,276 DEBUG [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] (default task-56) Checking persistence-unit [name=AAAAA_BBBB, explicit-provider=org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider] against incoming persistence unit name [AAAAA_BBBB]
2017-02-23 17:47:09,277 DEBUG [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] (default task-56) Excluding from consideration due to name mis-match
```

Additional Traces

2017-02-24 05:32:49,031 TRACE [org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.ProviderChecker] (default task-7) Checking requested PersistenceProvider name [org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider] against Hibernate provider names
2017-02-24 05:32:49,031 DEBUG [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] (default task-11) Excluding from consideration due to provider mis-match
2017-02-24 05:32:49,031 TRACE [org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.ProviderChecker] (default task-7) Found no match against Hibernate provider names

The persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="AAA_BBB" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>    
        <jta-data-source>java:/<jndi-Name in standalone</jta-data-source>
        <class>...</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="<url>"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="<username>"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="<pwd>"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="CCC_DDD" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>    
        <jta-data-source>java:/<jndi-Name in standalone</jta-data-source>       
        <class>...</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="<url>"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="<username>"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="<pwd>"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Where are you getting the exception "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named..."? Perhaps you can include some of the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added the stack trace in the Question itself now. To be more precise my entityJar are located in the modeules directory of Wildfly10.1.0Final. It contains the dpendency in the module.xml as well as org.eclipse.persistence is mentioned in the MANIFEST.MF of the entityJars

Comment: I am using EclipseLink 2.6.4 and Java 1.8. It was running fine in TOMCAT. Could this be a problem because I see EclipseLink 2.6.x requires Java 7, but there are no traces as such The minium version requried is Java 1.7, so i expect it shoud work also with JDK1.8.

Comment: Since the trace is showing `No Persistence provider for EntityManager named AAAAA_BBBB`, please include the persistence-unit AAAAA_BBBB in your question. More information is always good :)

Comment: Are you by chance including eclipselink in your deployment?

Comment: Nope..its no way present in any of the .war deployments.

Comment: Hi Will Dazey,

Added the persistence.xml in the question

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for the suggestions. The hibernate issue I was able to resolve it finally , although I still get the error "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named AAAAA_BBBB". In one of my modules and in the eclipselink module I was pointing to javax.persistence.api which turns out to contain the hibernate jar in Wildfly10.1. I added a new module in wildfly10.1.0 FINAL (javax.persistence.jar) and refered to the downloaded one and resolved it. Still the issue persists.

Comment: Can anybody shed some light on this please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was finally able to resolve the issue in a little weird way (probably)

Step 1 : created a module directory under the name (com.abc.persistence:main)
Step 2 copied all the related jars of eclipselink and jipijapa into the same module and referred it.

Step 2. Removed the system property "eclipselink.archive.factory"

It works clean.

What I analysed was if one of the system property is put then others like the target server are never added to the properties map (I checked somewhere in the code). Once I removed I think all the others also gets added and hence it works, because I will be little surprised if creating the above directory in the module (Step 1 above ) made it work.

Comment: Please what exactly did you mean by "and referred it"? How exactly did you do that? Can you edit your answer with details of your working configuration? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @SayoOladeji ,Sorry for replying late. 
To the first point of your question "and referred it" meant that I referred it from the module.xml.
In the standalone.xml, I removed the system property "eclipselink.archive.factory"